# How can I have a Usage as follow in python

Tags: python, argparse, sys

I was wondering how I could I have a usage like this:

`Usage: httpclient get [-v] [-h key: value] URL`

Basically, right now, I named my file httpclient.py so that I can call it by httpclient, and the rest is as follow:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument("arg1", nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument("arg2", nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument("-v",  nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument("-h", '--h', nargs='?', action='append')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.arg1 == "help" and (args.arg2 == "get" or args.arg2 == "post"):
        if args.arg2 == "get":
            gethelp()
        elif args.arg2 == "post":
            posthelp()
    elif args.arg1 == "help":
        help()
    elif args.arg1 == "get":
        if args.v:
            print(sys.argv[-1])
            get(args.v,1,args.h)
        else:
            get(sys.argv[2],0,args.h)
```

so right now if I do something as follow on the command line:

```
Py -3 httpclient.py get -v "http://google.com" -h "key: value"
```

however as you can see the url is place just after -v, where as in the task it is asked to be placed at the end, and exactly one url.

So everytime I write:

```
Py -3 httpclient.py get -v -h "key: value" "http://google.com"
```

I get an error:

```
usage: httpclient.py [-v [V]] [-h [H]] [arg1] [arg2]
httpc.py: error: unrecognized arguments: http://google.com
```

So how can I put the URL at the end of my cmd line arguments

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, but it looks like you should be using subparsers for `get` and `post` and `action='store_true'` for whatever `-v` is (verbose?) Why does it matter if the flags come before or after the URL?

Comment: -v is basically verbosity, if we add '-v' the output is going to show the headers of our get request, if you don't put '-v' then you will only the html response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using `nargs='?'` for a `-v`erbosity flag - you shouldn't expect *any* value to get passed for that, let alone *multiple* values.

---

Also it's odd to combine both `nargs='?'` and `action='append'`; do you want the user to do e.g. `-h one two` (`nargs='?'`) or `-h one -h two` (`action='append')` for the resulting `parsed_args.h == ['one', 'two']`?

Alternatively, if what you want for `-h` is to allow the user to set it multiple times, each time with a separate `key` and `value`, then what you want is:

```
parser.add_argument('-h', nargs=2, metavar=('key', 'value'), action='append')
```

---

It's pretty straightforward to take two optional arguments followed by a positional argument, and configure the display:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-v', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-h', metavar='key: value', action='append')
parser.add_argument('URL')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

Gets you:

```
$ python test.py
usage: test.py [-v] [-h key: value] URL
test.py: error: too few arguments
$ python test.py -h one -h two three
Namespace(URL='three', h=['one', 'two'], v=False)
$ python test.py hello -v
Namespace(URL='hello', h=None, v=True)
```

To add the separate `get` and `post` subcommands, look into using [`add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands); this will be much more effective than just allowing the user to give random input and comparing `== 'get'` etc.

However, it's not clear what you actually want the user interface to be, so it's hard to say precisely how you should implement it.

Comment: Yes for -h I want to be able to do either `-h hello: World -h world: hello` and `-h hello: world world:hello` and for the rest thank you, it all makes sense now

Comment: @puzzle don't allow either, that is going to add a lot of overhead to the parsing. If you make the interface `-h hello world -h world hello` then `argparse` can do all of the work for you, giving `[['hello', 'world'], ['world', 'hello']]` without you having to intervene. Also, note http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I was wondering, as my first argument I can have help, get and post, if I have help I can only have get or post after, such that 

`httpclient help` would give a broad help section

and

`httpclient help get` or `httpclient help post` would give a much more precise help. 

this is possible with subparsers? if so how would I implement that?

Comment: @puzzle yes, you can nest them; each one can have its own `help`.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("arg1", nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("arg2", nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("-v",  nargs='?')
parser.add_argument("-h", '--h', nargs='?', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args()

parser.print_help()

print(args)
```

test runs:

```
1438:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py 
usage: stack41863442.py [-v [V]] [-h [H]] [arg1] [arg2]

positional arguments:
  arg1
  arg2

optional arguments:
  -v [V]
  -h [H], --h [H]
Namespace(arg1=None, arg2=None, h=None, v=None)

1526:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py get -v -h "key: value"
....
Namespace(arg1='get', arg2=None, h=['key: value'], v=None)

1527:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py get -v -h "key: value" google
usage: stack41863442.py [-v [V]] [-h [H]] [arg1] [arg2]
stack41863442.py: error: unrecognized arguments: google
```

Putting the 2nd positional argument right after the first works:

```
1528:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py get google -v -h "key: value" 
...
Namespace(arg1='get', arg2='google', h=['key: value'], v=None)
```

A `nargs='?'` Action is satisfied by an empty list.  So `arg2` is parsed right after `arg1`, leaving nothing to handle the `google`.

```
python stack41863442.py -v -h "key: value" get google
```

creates the same namespace.

Be careful with multiple variable nargs arguments.  They don't always work together well.

The `-v` will be a lot more useful if give it `const` and `default` values.   e.g. with defaults for the postionals as well:

```
1536:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py 
Namespace(arg1='def1', arg2='def2', h=None, v='vdef')
1536:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py -v
Namespace(arg1='def1', arg2='def2', h=None, v='vconst')
1536:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py -v fpp
Namespace(arg1='def1', arg2='def2', h=None, v='fpp')
```

Here `get` is assigned to `-v`:

```
1538:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py -v get google
Namespace(arg1='google', arg2='def2', h=None, v='get')
```

For a `verbosity` 'switch', a `store_true` action might be better.  `count` action also is used if you want to use `-vvv` to signal extra verbose'.

I didn't notice `-h` 'append', but I agree with the other answer.  That's an odd combination.  What is `-h` without any following argument supposed to mean?  In this test, the bare `-h` puts a `None` (default) in the `h` list.

```
1540:~/mypy$ python stack41863442.py -h test -h -h 'other;x'
Namespace(arg1='def1', arg2='def2', h=['test', None, 'other;x'], v='vdef')
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, as this explain very well the issues that I was having